# PHP Вернуть значения массива ключ которых содержит строку

Tags: php, массивы, key

Есть такой массив:

```
array() { ["question_result_1"]=> string(1) "111" ["question_result_2"]=> string(1) "222" ["teacher_id"]=> string(1) "1" ["do_send"]=> string(0) "" }
```

Нужно вернуть значения только тех элементов, ключи которых содержат "question_result_"

В примере с моим массивом должно вернуть `array("111", "222");`
Как это можно реализовать?

Comment: `array_filter()` и подставляйте фильтр, что душе угодно

Comment: пример можно? с ключом "question_result_"

Comment: пример `strpos($mystring, 'question_result_') === 0`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант:

```
$array = array_values(array_filter($array, function($key) {
     return strpos($key, 'question_result_') === 0;
 }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```